# how to set image in textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox in my application that I want to add an image to.

In some cases I'd like both an image and text.

Is it possible and how can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" TextChanged="OnTextBoxTextChanged" Width="200">
  <TextBox.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="TextBoxBackground.gif" AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None" />
  </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

From C#

```
// Create an ImageBrush.
ImageBrush textImageBrush = new ImageBrush();
textImageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"TextBoxBackground.gif", UriKind.Relative));
textImageBrush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left;
textImageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
// Use the brush to paint the button's background.
myTextBox.Background = textImageBrush;
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590.aspx)

Comment: Is it also possible to offset the text so it doesn't overlay the icon?