# TextBox with image icon in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, textbox

I want to create `TextBox` with image in it. This is what I have tried:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" >
    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="D:\my_backup\WPF\SALIENT\SALIENT\Images\d2.PNG" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
        <TextBox  Text="test" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"                                    
        </TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

this gives me output like this: [image: img]

but i want the image inside `TextBox` like this[image: img]

anyone can help?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070906/how-to-set-image-in-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: yes i tried this..but in that case.my text is going over image

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use this sort of implementation.
you should probably make a user control out of it.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="2"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            CornerRadius="5">

        <StackPanel Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image Source="C:\SourceOfTheImage\Path\Image.png" 
                   Height="18"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello, I am a text block!"
                       Margin="3 0 0 0"/>

        </StackPanel>


    </Border>
```

It looks like this for me

[image]

Comment: This answer is using a non-editable `TextBlock`, while the question asks about adding an image to a `TextBox`. I think A.Pissicat's answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can set the background property on Textbox, like this (mine is align on right) :

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch"
         Text="Search Item...">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Search.png" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Right">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-3"/>                        
                </TransformGroup>
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

Set `AlignmentX` to left if you want to see the image on the left side. Set the `TranslateTransform.X` to a positive value to add a margin.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<Border Padding="5" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2">
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" >
         <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="D:\my_backup\WPF\SALIENT\SALIENT\Images\d2.PNG" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
         <TextBox  Text="test" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" ></TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

That would be the simplest one-off way of doing it. 
You could dump it in a UserControl for reuse.

A second way of achieving this would be to open up the TextBox template and put this icon of yours inside the makeup of the TextBox, which would allow you to avoid needing the DockPanel and Border here, as well as allowing you to make the Template a resource you can easily attach to any Textbox in the future.